# How will a display a card with input many times based on input from increment and decrement button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a code with increment and decrement button:

```
<div class="form-group border-dark" id="quantity">
  <label class="text-center"><strong>Quantity:</strong></label><br>
 <span class= "btn-danger quantity-decrement fa fa-minus">
 </span>
          <input type="text" class="quantity" id="quant" name="quant" value="1" min="1" max="100" disabled>
           <span class= "btn-info quantity-increment fa fa-plus">
 </span>
   </div>
```

and another like this:

```
    <div style="display:none" class = "eventdetail">
    <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <label class="pull-right" id="none"></label>
           <label id="con"></label><br>
            <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>

             <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                   <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
                </div>
             </div>
            <section class="row">
                <div align="center">
                      <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove" >Remove Ticket</a>
                </div>
             </section>                         
        </div>

     </div>
</div>
 <div id = "eventdisplay">
 </div>
```

i want #eventdetail to be displayed the number of times i made with the increment button in #eventdisplay. please how can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
You should read this [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could make #event-detail a template using the html5 template tag (although its not fully cross browser compliant) and on each button click - create a node and append it to the location you want it it. Note you will need to make the id dynamic since you can only have unique id's in the page.

Comment: Please i'm a beginner in programming. can you illustrate what you mean?

Comment: please i need help... I'm stock at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that tried to answer my question. i found a way around it. for those that may have the same problem, this is my solution:

```
$("#proceedevent").click(function() {

    var item = $('.eventdetail').show(); 

    count = parseInt($("#quant").val(), 10) - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < count;i++){
        item.clone(true).appendTo('#eventdisplay');

    }
  $('.remove').click( function(){
           if($('.eventdetail').length > 1) {
                 $(this).closest(".eventdetail").remove();
            }else{
             $('.remove').hide();
            }
    });

});
```

this is what i did;

```
 var item = $('.eventdetail').show();
```

this is the class i am cloning, it was hidden before, so i have to show it.

```
 count = parseInt($("#quant").val(), 10) - 1;
```

then the number of times i want to clone it. this is from my increment button in the main question.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < count;i++){
        item.clone(true).appendTo('#eventdisplay');

    }
```

the clone

```
  $('.remove').click( function(){
           if($('.eventdetail').length > 1) {
                 $(this).closest(".eventdetail").remove();
            }else{
             $('.remove').hide();
            }
    });
```

i used this to remove the cloned part one at a time except the last one.